# I cant add loop cuts

Tags: modifiers

[image] I have a model and want to shrink or press or bend on red axis show in the image to make the shape as shown in reference image. I cant add loop cut & if i add sub division modifier i loose all the sharpness of the edges. U can try with my model i have attach the file.....[image]

**Added lattice and modified little bit to get the shape**

[image]

confused problem 
[image]

with the reference video i have yet to error[image]

Comment: Loop cuts work only on connected faces made of quads, Polygons with less or more than 4 vertices will break the loop, as well as unconnected or duplicated vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press Shift+A and add a lattice
[image: lattice]
after that, select the object to be deformed and add a lattice modifier
[image: latticemodifier] Under the modifier, make sure you select the lattice as the object [image: lattice_object] select your lattice, and go to edit mode, pressing TAB key; press Shift+leftclick to select the 4 vertices on the -Y direction of the lattice, press S to scale them.[image: deforming_lattice] I've uploaded your blend file with the lattice: [image]

Comment: yes thats what i need thanks learning from expert is great

Comment: Im little bit confuse with my file or with the method plz i want to confirm as i do not want mean time my problem to be solve i like life time problem to be solve when ever i use it should work same way and with perfection. As in the image i have taken the lattice and add 3x3 cut and then i click on my model and add the lattice modifier. going into the edit mode as i see that the corner when stretch it works but with the center it did not work. Sorry for repeating the question again. What im doing is the correct way or can u plz explain whats the correct and where im going wrong

Comment: instead of 3x3, try 4x4 and scale the middle group of vertices. Do a lattice form like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NbzlQVmloE

Comment: as seen in the video i have did still error i have attach the file and image whats the problem going on [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2192" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2192/)

Comment: Under the lattice menu (between modfifiers and texture icon), change your values (U,V, and W) to 4, instead of 3 (like the lattice in the video). Then select all the vertices in the middle (remember to select the ones on the other side, and the ones in the middle), press S to scale.

Comment: Can u plz download my file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2192/ and see the error i have made the section but the middle section not working only the 4 corner are working

Comment: i got the solution i subdivide the model 2 times and then add the lattice modifier and got the shape. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a pure quad mesh. Loop cuts will only work with a mesh that the faces are 4 sided, and what you have is a n-gon mesh (sometimes 3 sides, sometimes 5 sides, or even more) - you have to remesh to a pure quad mesh, consider retopology techniques using mainly squares or rectangles to build the mesh. Another problem is your normals, that are not consistent: while in Edit mode, select all, press space write "consistent" and select "make normals consistent"; or recalculate the normals. In case you don't want to do retopology, you can add curve objects and use modifier deform by curves, or even add a lattice object and deform your "steel object" by it, using lattice modifier.

Comment: Yeah ur right i don't want to do again. lattice is not working i tried it. can u tell me modifier deform by curves how it works i never used it

Comment: well, I just performed the lattice modifier to your object and it worked. I'll add another answer explaining how to. wait a bit

Comment: i have attach my result file

Comment: Well done! Next time, you want to model something like this, remember the quad rule! The tricky parts will be when you want to perform boolean modifiers, like the circles you carved! you have to match the number of vertices to neighbour number of vertices, to keep quadrangle faces. Please look for tutorials on retopoly faces, and see how they manage around the eyes.

Comment: other thing, when you apply subdivision surfaces and you want to get some sharp edges, select the edges you want to be sharp, press N (for right lateral menu), under "transform", increase the "crease" value to 1, and that edge will be sharper than the others.